# Calculate height of Divs around a Div thats height is based on parent width?

Tags: css

I have an outer div with the following (condensed to show only relevant) CSS attributes:

```
.container{
position:relative;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:calc(100% - 80px);
margin-left:40px;
height:calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

Inside it I have three divs, the top one containing introductory text, the middle one holding content, and the bottom one for visitor comments. The middle one will be a photo slideshow, video clip, map etc. So needs to be a specific aspect ratio, given the width is fluid I am using the following (sample 2:1 ratio) CSS:

```
.videoplayer{
position:absolute;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:calc(100% - 40px);
left:20px;
top:50%;
height:0px;
padding-top:calc(25% - 10px);
padding-bottom:calc(25% - 10px);
transform:translate(0,-50%);
}
```

By using zero height and making the height from % vertical padding it creates it's height dynamically based on the width of the parent, then top:50%; and transform:translate(0,-50%); position it centrally within the parent div.

The problem I have is I want the divs that go above and below this one to fit the remaining space above and below it, and I have no idea how to calculate their height!

The final result I am looking for is:[THIS](http://i.imgur.com/6jaP7lr.png)

Anyone know if this is possible (Ideally with pure CSS) and if so how?

Many thanks :)

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS, since you're effectively asking how to style two (one preceding and one subsequent) siblings of a given element, and CSS has no means by which a previous sibling can be selected. Having said that, it might be possible with flex-box; can you show the relevant HTML for this section?

Comment: The html is as follows:  

    <DIV class="videocontainer">

    <DIV class="videotext"></DIV>

    <DIV class="videoplayer"></DIV>

    <DIV class="videocomments"> </DIV>

    </DIV>

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I want my screen looks like the same in all pc desktop browser, all mobile browser, all Android phones and all iPhones.

so I set the outer div height to screen available height.  I have 3 inner div, top div height = screen height / 14, bottom div height = screen height / 14, middle div Height = screen height * 12 / 14

I never use something like 20px since every screen's 20px is different, I use (screen height / some number)px instead

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @David-Thomas for pointing me in the direction of flex-box with which I managed to sort it out! Solution below in case anyone else has the same problem.

```
.videocontainer{    /* PARENT DIV - FLUID HEIGHT TO FILL VIEWPORT */
position:relative;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:calc(100% - 80px);
margin-left:40px;
height:calc(100% - 80px);
display:inline-flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:center;
align-content:stretch;
align-items:stretch;
}

.videotext{    /* DIV HEIGHT FLUID TO FILL SPACE ABOVE */
flex:1;
width:calc(100% - 40px);
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}  

.videoplayer{    /* DIV HEIGHT FIXED RATIO TO WIDTH */
box-sizing:border-box;
width:calc(100% - 40px); 
margin-left:20px;   
height:0px;
padding-top:calc(25% - 10px);
padding-bottom:calc(25% - 10px);
}

.videocomments{    /* DIV HEIGHT FLUID TO FILL SPACE BELOW */
flex:1;
width:calc(100% - 40px);
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```